# How to set TextField's underline color?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

How do you set the color of the line in `TextField` to another color?

With Material theme you can change "Material.accent" color, but I want to change the permanent color, not only when the line gets focus.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 types of `TextField` - QtQuick2 and QtControls2. Assuming that you use the last one you can customize the control as you want, including the line color. For example:

```js
TextField {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    background: Item {
        implicitWidth: 200
        implicitHeight: 40
        Rectangle {
            color: "yellow"
            height: 3
            width: parent.width
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you check source code of the Material style you see next:

```js
        background: Rectangle {
            y: source.height - height - source.bottomPadding + 8
            implicitWidth: 120
            height: source.activeFocus || source.hovered ? 2 : 1
            color: source.activeFocus ? source.Material.accentColor
                                       : (source.hovered ? source.Material.primaryTextColor : source.Material.hintTextColor)
        }
```

So for add support custom color of TextField line you need to add one property and replace **source.Material.hintTextColor** to your custom color.

```js
    TextField {
        id: source
        property color lineColor: "#ff00ff"
        background: Rectangle {
            y: source.height - height - source.bottomPadding + 8
            implicitWidth: 120
            height: source.activeFocus || source.hovered ? 2 : 1
            color: source.activeFocus ? source.Material.accentColor
                                       : (source.hovered ? source.Material.primaryTextColor : source.lineColor)
        }
    }
```